# How to get "Capabilities" of a PnP device in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-10, wmi, windows-driver, windows-hello

Is there a WMI or PowerShell way to get the [Capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ns-wdm-_device_capabilities) of a Plug and Play device like a WebCam?

I am looking for a programmatic way to enumerate or check if a Capability value, particularly `CM_DEVCAP_SECUREDDEVICE` (like in image listed below) is present/applicable for a camera device or not.

[image]

I *was* able to get the property key `DEVPKEY_Device_Capabilities` but, per [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/devpkey-device-capabilities):

> The value of DEVPKEY_Device_Capabilities is a bitwise OR of the CM_DEVCAP_Xxx capability flags

which doesn't give me enough granularity to know whether that specific capability is available or not (or does it and I don't understand it? ).

```
Get-PnpDevice -PresentOnly -Class Camera | Get-PnpDeviceProperty -KeyName DEVPKEY_Device_Capabilities

InstanceId KeyName                                   Type       Data
---------- -------                                   ----       ----
USB\VID... DEVPKEY_Device_Capabilities               UInt32     164
```

To note, I do not know in advance whether a device in the pool of devices/cameras I have to check against definitely have it enabled (nor do I have a way to procure one), so I cannot know the value of the `DEVPKEY_Device_Capabilities` property in advance to compare against too.

Comment: Take a look into [`CM_DRP_CAPABILITIES` enum](https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-10/blob/master/Include/10.0.16299.0/um/cfgmgr32.h), you find all `CM_DEVCAP_*` values there…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value stored as `DEVPKEY_Device_Capabilities` is a bitfield mapping to the capabilities defined in `Cfgmgr32.h` - easiest way to parse the value is to define an `enum` type with the `[Flags()]` attribute then convert the value to that:

```
[Flags()]
enum DeviceCapabilities {
  LOCKSUPPORTED      = 0x0001
  EJECTSUPPORTED     = 0x0002
  REMOVABLE          = 0x0004
  DOCKDEVICE         = 0x0008
  UNIQUEID           = 0x0010
  SILENTINSTALL      = 0x0020
  RAWDEVICEOK        = 0x0040
  SURPRISEREMOVALOK  = 0x0080
  HARDWAREDISABLED   = 0x0100
  NONDYNAMIC         = 0x0200
  SECUREDEVICE       = 0x0400
}
```

Now we can do:

```
PS ~> Get-PnpDevice -Class Camera -PresentOnly |Select FriendlyName,InstanceId,@{Name='Capabilities';Expression={($_ |Get-PnpDeviceProperty -KeyName DEVPKEY_Device_Capabilities).Data -as [DeviceCapabilities]}}

InstanceId FriendlyName                               Capabilities
---------- ------------                               ------------
USB\VID... PC camera    REMOVABLE, SILENTINSTALL, SUPRISEREMOVALOK
```

---

Note: As you may have noticed, the `SECUREDEVICE` capability flag shows up in the property window, but the value associated with `DEVPKEY_Device_Capabilities` appears to only hold the lower 8 bits - I'm afraid I don't know where Explorer gets the rest :)